# XSS in input field bypass HTML entities

Tags: xss

I am auditing a web application and trying to exploit XSS in the value attribute of an input field. While fuzzing I figured out that the application is filtering `<` and `>` so I changed my payload but the application is converting `"` into `&quot`. Without completing the attribute value with the quote, the payload will not work.

The insertion point is marked with `USER INPUT` below:

```
<input name="xyz" value="USER INPUT" type="text">
```

How can I exploit this?

Comment: Is this DOM based XSS or reflected?If its reflected can you provide the response part where  your payload is  reflecting?

Comment: exploit what? you just said it won't work...

Answer (score 0):

You can't. It sounds like they are protecting against XSS properly.

HTML entities (`&quot;`, `&gt;`, `&lt;`, etc.) are not interpreted as HTML and turning "dangerous" characters into entities is one of the ideal ways to protect against XSS.